# Find and replace words using sed command not working

Tags: linux, sed

I have a a text file which is tab separated, the first column holds the word to be found and the second column holds the word to replace the found word. This text file contains English and Arabic pairs. Once the word is found and replaced it should not be changed again.

For example:

```
adam    a +dam
a   b
ال  ال+
```

So for a given text file:

```
adam played with a ball ال
```

I expect:

```
a +dam played with b ball ال+
```

However, I get:

```
b +dbm plbyed with b bbll ال+
```

I am using the following sed command to find and replace:

```
sed -e 's/^/s%/' -e 's/\t/%/' -e 's/$/%g/' tab_sep_file.txt | sed -f - original_file.txt >replaced.txt
```

How can I fix this issue

Comment: Be a lot easier using awk.

Comment: The tricky part comes from not wanting to replace any matches in the text of a previous replacement.

Comment: @Shawn can you give me a hint on how to do that, or from where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem to your approach is that you don't want to replace matched text in a prior substitution with a later one - you don't want to change the *a*'s in *a +dam* to *b*'s. This makes `sed` a pretty poor choice - you can make a regular expression that matches all of the things you want to replace fairly easily, but picking which replacement to use is an issue.

A way using GNU `awk`:

```sh
gawk -F'\t' '
     FNR == NR { subs[$1] = $2; next } # populate the array of substitutions
     ENDFILE {
             if (FILENAME == ARGV[1]) {
                # Build a regular expression of things to substitute
                subre = "\\<("
                first=0
                for (s in subs)
                    subre = sprintf("%s%s%s", subre, first++ ? "|" : "", s)
                subre = sprintf("%s)\\>", subre)
             }
     }
     {
        # Do the substitution
        nwords = patsplit($0, words, subre, between)
        printf "%s", between[0]
        for (n = 1; n <= nwords; n++)
            printf "%s%s", subs[words[n]], between[n]
        printf "\n"
     }
' tab_sep_file.txt original_file.txt
```

which outputs

```
a +dam played with b ball
```

First it reads the TSV file and builds an array of words to be replaced and text to replace it with (`subs`). Then after reading that file, it builds a regular expression to match all possible words to be found - `\<(a|adam)\>` in this case. The `\<` and `\>` match only at the beginning and end, respectively, of words, so the *a* in *ball* won't match.

Then for the second file with the text you want to process, it uses `patsplit()` to split each line into an array of matched parts (`words`) and the bits between matches (`between`), and iterates over the length of the array, printing out the replacement text for each match. That way it avoids re-matching text that's already been replaced.

---

And a `perl` version that uses a similar approach (Taking advantage of `perl`'s ability to evaluate the replacement text in a `s///` substitution):

```sh
perl -e '
     use strict;
     use warnings;
     # Set file/standard stream char encodings from locale
     use open ":locale"; 
     # Or for explicit UTF-8 text
     # use open ":encoding(UTF-8)", ":std";
     my %subs;
     open my $words, "<", shift or die $!;
     while (<$words>) {
        chomp;
        my ($word, $rep) = split "\t" ,$_, 2;
        $subs{$word} = $rep;
     }
     my $subre = "\\b(?:" . join("|", map { quotemeta } keys %subs) . ")\\b";
     while (<<>>) {
       print s/$subre/$subs{$&}/egr;
     }
' tab_sep_file.txt original_file.txt
```

(This one will escape regular expression metacharacters in the words to replace, making it more robust)

Comment: thanks a lot it's working fine, but I have some find-replace pairs that are Arabic (non English), so the \b word boundary is not working with them for the perl script

Comment: @M.A.G stuff like that is important to mention in your question (and include in the sample data)

Comment: I updated my question and sample data to include Arabic

Comment: @M.A.G Updated the perl version to work with non-ASCII text.